# HTTP request logs needed for anaylsis

Tags: logging, http, log-files

I'm looking for detailed server logs of HTTP requests, so that I can find the most common HTTP request header values for fields such as User-Agent, Accept, Accept-Charset, etc..  I found a resource for the [User-Agent field](http://techblog.willshouse.com/2012/01/03/most-common-user-agents/), but nothing for the rest.  If I had a webserver that got a lot of traffic, then I could log this information.  Does anyone share this sort of information publicly?  Where can I find it?

Thanks for your help.

Background: I'm working on a project for grad school, which is about application level fingerprinting of web browsers.  The goal of the project is to be able to hide from the type of identification demonstrated by [Panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/)

Update:  I don't have a server, and even if I did I wouldn't have the traffic necessary to perform a meaningful analysis.  Blau is correct, I'm looking for public domain web server logs.

Comment: i remember nagious monitoring had a component for do it. please see nagious repo.

Comment: Please indicate which web server you're using along with the operating system

Comment: Your are looking for public domain webserver access logs.

Comment: Lots of sites have let their server logs leak onto the Internet, though I presume you'll run into ethics issues if you attempt to use them.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Apache server, you have to take a look [Custom Log Formats](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats) specifically the entry for `%{VARNAME}i`.